# Testing Non-consumable In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am trying to create my first non-consumable in app purchase for my ios app and I just uploaded the .pkg to iTunes Connect (via XCode) but I still see this warning...

`This In-App Purchase is not currently available for testing in the sandbox environment because you have chosen to host your content with Apple, but have not delivered your content. Upload your content to test this In-App Purchase in sandbox.`

and the status is still

`Waiting for Upload`

I have not yet submitted my App's binary yet however.

How do I get rid of the message above and move on with testing in the sandbox env? Do I need to submit my app's binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! I guess I was just being impatient. I checked back after a couple of hours and now the warning message has changed to

`Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.`

For those who also got confused because they did not notify you directly, just make sure that you:
Archive your in app purchase, distribute it through XCode (Open organizer) and wait 1-2 hours.

Answer (score -2):

This error came up for me when I edited an in-app purchase.

I have not received a reply from Apple but found that when I changed the image, I got this on saving.

Instead of being an edit, it turned into an add new.

As I have quite a few apps, I decided to add the in app-purchases to them and found that there was an issue with the graphic. There is no need to change the old one but thought it would be nice.

It is buggy.

I resolved the problem by deleting the new in app purchase and the edits were still saved into the original configuration except for the image.

Comment: why do you shout (aka: all caps) - please fix your keyboard and edit your answer ...